# Why does log applied to a vector with a magrittr pipe give unexpected & incorrect values?

Tags: r, magrittr

I am trying to compute the entropy of a discrete distribution and I noticed the behavior using magrittr is not what I expected. To give an example:

```
> x <- c("A","B","C","A","A","D")                                                                                                 
> table(x)/length(x) %>% log2                                                                                                     
x
        A         B         C         D
 1.1605584 0.3868528 0.3868528 0.3868528
```

Which is not correct---the logs of values less than 1 should be negative. If I break up the steps, I get the correct answer:

```
> freq <- table(x)/length(x)                                                                                                      
> log2(freq)                                                                                                                      
 x
         A         B         C         D
 -1.000000 -2.584963 -2.584963 -2.584963
```

Comment: You're doing the equivalent of `table(x)/log2(length(x))` I'm guessing `length(x) %>% log2` is being evaluated first and then being used in the division operation.

Comment: See `?Syntax`. Special operators like `%>%` have higher precedence than `/`.

Comment: They should stop teaching [BODMAS](https://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/bodmas.html) in primary schools, and start teaching BPODMAS. Brackets, Pipe operator, Orders, etc...

Comment: (table(x)/length(x)) %>% log2(.)

Answer (score 2):

This could work, must be a fan of many pipes :)

```
library(magrittr)
x %>% table %>% divide_by(x %>% length) %>% log2
```

`magrittr` offers also divide_by, multiply_by etc. You could also skip the package and use the following syntax

```
x %>% table %>% `/`(x %>% length) %>% log2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems using a pipe, it can be helpful to use the core `dplyr` verbs (`select`, `mutate`, `filter`, etc) to make it more obvious what you're trying to do.

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>% 
  tbl_df() %>%                   # Convert to a tibble
  group_by(value) %>% 
  summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%  # Calculate frequency
  mutate(log = log2(freq))       # Here's log2
```

Comment: I disagree, piping happens to be used by `dplyr`, but it's a valid wherever you want.

Comment: That's a fair point, @Axeman. I reworded my answer accordingly.

Comment: Who said assembler was dead?